# Webpack not extracting CSS into files from vendor vue components

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vue-loader

I have a problem with webpack not extracting CSS from **vendor** VUE components.

Html head looks like this: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbtkC.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbtkC.png.)

All these style tags are from **vendor** Vue components only. Inserted after page load from Javascript

Other styles in mine vue components, mine LESS files, styles from **non-vue** vendor packages are correctly splitted into **main.css** and **vendor.css**

What is missing from config ? (bottom)

Thanx

**webpack.config.js**

```
    const webpack = require('webpack');
    const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
    const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
    const OptimizeCSSPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
    const utils = require('./utils');

    const path = require('path');
    const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

    const SRC_PATH = path.join(__dirname, 'src');
    const DIST_PATH = path.join(__dirname, !isProduction ? 'www-dev' : 'www');

    function resolve(dir) {
        return path.join(__dirname, '../', dir)
    }

    module.exports = {

        devtool: !isProduction ? 'inline-source-map' : undefined,

        entry: {
            main: [
                SRC_PATH + '/main.less',
                SRC_PATH + '/main.js',
            ]
        },

        output: {
            path: DIST_PATH,
            publicPath: '',
            filename: !isProduction ? '[name].js' : '[name].min.js?c=[chunkhash]',
            sourceMapFilename: !isProduction ? '[name].js.map' : undefined
        },

        module: {
            rules: utils.styleLoaders({ sourceMap: true, extract: true })
                .concat([{
                        test: /\.vue$/,
                        loader: 'vue-loader',
                        options: {
                            loaders: utils.cssLoaders({
                                sourceMap: true,
                                extract: true
                            })
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        test: /\.js$/,
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        exclude: /node_modules/
                    },
                    {
                        test: /\.(woff2?|ttf|eot|otf)$/,
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: path => {
                                if(!/node_modules|bower_components/.test(path))
                                    return 'fonts/[name].[hash].[ext]';

                                return 'fonts/vendor/' + path
                                    .replace(/\\/g, '/')
                                    .replace(
                                        /((.*(node_modules|bower_components))|fonts|font|assets)\//g, ''
                                    ) + '?[hash]';
                            },
                            publicPath: './'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        test: /\.(bmp|png|jpe?g|gif|svg|ico|ani|cur)$/,
                        loaders: [{
                                loader: 'file-loader',
                                options: {
                                    name: path => {
                                        if(!/node_modules|bower_components/.test(path))
                                            return 'images/[name].[hash].[ext]';

                                        return 'images/vendor/' + path
                                            .replace(/\\/g, '/')
                                            .replace(
                                                /((.*(node_modules|bower_components))|images|image|img|assets)\//g, ''
                                            ) + '?[hash]';
                                    },
                                    publicPath: './'
                                }
                            },
                            'img-loader'
                        ]
                    }
                ])
        },
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
                '~': resolve('node_modules'),
                '@': resolve('src')
            }
        },
        plugins: [],

        performance: {
            hints: false
        }
    }

    //Dev & Production plugins
    module.exports.plugins.push(

        //Environment
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: '"' + (!isProduction ? 'development' : 'production') + '"'
            }
        }),

        //Extract CSS to file
        new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: !isProduction ? '[name].css?c=[chunkhash]' : '[name].min.css?c=[chunkhash]' }),

        //Extract vendor CSS/JS
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'vendor',
            minChunks: function(module) {
                return module.context && module.context.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1;
            }
        }),

        //Extract html
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: SRC_PATH + '/index.html',
            inject: true,
            chunksSortMode: 'dependency',
            minify: !isProduction ? undefined : {
                removeComments: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                removeAttributeQuotes: true
            }
        })
    );


    if(!isProduction)
    //Development stuff
        module.exports.plugins.push(

        // Hot module replacement..DUNNO
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),

        // Use the NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin to skip the emitting 
        // phase whenever there are errors while compiling. 
        // This ensures that no assets are emitted that include errors.
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
    );
    else
    //Production
        module.exports.plugins.push(

        // Optimize CSS
        new OptimizeCSSPlugin({
            cssProcessorOptions: {
                safe: true
            }
        }),

        // Minify JS
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            sourceMap: true,
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            }
        })
    );
```

**utils.js**

```
    const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

    exports.cssLoaders = function(options) {
        options = options || {}

        var cssLoader = {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
                minimize: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
                sourceMap: options.sourceMap
            }
        }

        // generate loader string to be used with extract text plugin
        function generateLoaders(loader, loaderOptions) {
            var loaders = [cssLoader]
            if(loader) {
                loaders.push({
                    loader: loader + '-loader',
                    options: Object.assign({}, loaderOptions, {
                        sourceMap: options.sourceMap
                    })
                })
            }

            // Extract CSS when that option is specified
            // (which is the case during production build)
            if(options.extract) {
                return ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    use: loaders,
                    fallback: 'vue-style-loader'
                })
            } else {
                return ['vue-style-loader'].concat(loaders)
            }
        }

        // https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/configurations/extract-css.html
        return {
            css: generateLoaders(),
            postcss: generateLoaders(),
            less: generateLoaders('less'),
            sass: generateLoaders('sass', { indentedSyntax: true }),
            scss: generateLoaders('sass'),
            stylus: generateLoaders('stylus'),
            styl: generateLoaders('stylus')
        }
    }

    // Generate loaders for standalone style files (outside of .vue)
    exports.styleLoaders = function(options) {
        var output = []
        var loaders = exports.cssLoaders(options)
        for(var extension in loaders) {
            var loader = loaders[extension]
            output.push({
                test: new RegExp('\\.' + extension + '$'),
                use: loader
            })
        }
        return output
    }
```

**package.json**

```
    {
      "name": "vue-test",
      "description": "A Vue.js project",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "author": "",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --hot --config=webpack.dev.config.js",
        "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --config=webpack.config.js --progress --hide-modules",
        "watch": "npm run build -- --watch",
        "release": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config=webpack.config.js --progress --hide-modules"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.16.2",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
        "velocity-animate": "^1.5.0",
        "vue": "^2.4.1",
        "vue-directive-tooltip": "^1.2.3",
        "vue-image-lightbox": "^5.5.3",
        "vue-images": "^1.0.10",
        "vue-js-modal": "^1.2.2",
        "vue-lazyload": "^1.0.6",
        "vue-router": "^2.7.0",
        "vue-select": "^2.2.0",
        "vue-touch": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
        "vue2-dropzone": "^2.3.5",
        "vuejs-datepicker": "^0.9.4",
        "vuetify": "^0.13.1",
        "vuex": "^2.3.1",
        "vuex-router-sync": "^4.2.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.0.0",
        "babel-loader": "^6.0.0",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.5.1",
        "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
        "bulma": "^0.4.3",
        "cross-env": "^3.0.0",
        "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
        "cssnano": "^3.10.0",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
        "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.29.0",
        "img-loader": "^2.0.0",
        "less": "^2.7.2",
        "less-loader": "^4.0.4",
        "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
        "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
        "sass-loader": "^5.0.1",
        "vue-loader": "^13.0.2",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.3.3",
        "webpack": "^2.6.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I can't paste image directly (You need 10 reputation points to post images) and included Gist is too long. What should I do with it ?